# How to fetch data from mysql when press button?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to fetch data randomly from mysql when click button,here is my code.

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","school");
// Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT description From task ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2");
    echo "<p><strong>Question:</strong></p>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo "<p>". $row['description'] ."</p>";

}

    mysqli_close($con);
?>

     <input type="button" value="Get Assignment" onclick="myfunc()">

</body>
</html>
```

I expect the output when i'm clicking Get Assignment button it will display random question, until i will display empty box.

Comment: You have informed us of your desire ( "I expect ..." ), but have neglected to describe what is working, what not or to ask a question. Have you encountered any specific problem or error message? Does it work in some cases only? Does it return wrong results or nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your php code to `isset` function which will check if data is send then run else don't.

> **isset function check if variable is set & not  null**

alternatively you can call Ajax to append data on click. [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-ajax-in-php-and-jquery--cms-32494)

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","school");
// Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT description From task ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2");
    echo "<p><strong>Question:</strong></p>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo "<p>". $row['description'] ."</p>";

}

    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>

     <input type="button" name="submit" value="Get Assignment" onclick="myfunc()">

</body>
</html>
```

**edit**  fixed my code

you need to wrap your input button to a form which will submit the form to the page itself

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Assignment">
</form>
```

Comment: Your php code does return any thing before clicking.. What i mean try your code without any click just simple code on page to test whether it run or not. are you able to make SQL queries. if you can then we'll continue on php to fetch data on click.

Comment: Yes without click button... it's working when ever i reload page qus are change randomly.

Comment: Now i got it  ...yeahhh it's working thanks a lotttttttt